# PHP pdo fetch only returning 1 result

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

**pdo function:**

```
        public function selectByCatagory($catagory,$column,$table,$id){
        $query =  $this->_pdo->prepare('SELECT ' .$column. ' FROM ' .$table. ' WHERE   catagory=:catagory');
        $query->bindParam(':catagory', $catagory);
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetch();
        return $result[$id];
    }
```

Function use:

```
            for($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++){
        $title = database::getInstance()->selectByCatagory($catagory, 'subject' , 'web_forum' ,$i);        
        echo $title

             }
```

The problem occurs when getting the offset 1. It says there is no offset 1 but when i run it in my database program there are 9 other results.

Comment: [`fetch`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) only returns the first row. To get the other rows, you have to call it again.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, that was stupid of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) indeed returns only one row from the result set. If you want them all, you'd have to use [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) or iterate over the result set yourself:

```
public function selectByCatagory($catagory,$column,$table,$id){
    $query =  $this->_pdo->prepare('SELECT ' .$column. ' FROM ' .$table. ' WHERE   catagory=:catagory');
    $query->bindParam(':catagory', $catagory);
    $query->execute();

    $retVal = array();
    while ($result = $query->fetch()) {
        array_push($retVal, $result[$id]);
    }
    return $retVal;
}
```